# How do I implement a handler for ZAP?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I'm currently trying to learn ZeroMQ and wanted to implement a handler for ZAP so that I can authenticate clients. I looked at the test file test_security_curve.cpp in the libzmq repository and noticed that it uses many helper functions. I don't know if I need those or not.

How would I go about implementing ZAP authentication with modern C++? Should I even use libzmq or switch to cppzmq or zmqpp? I'm really confused about this..

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using czmq, which is the so-called high-level API, instead of libzmq. It also has a C++ binding, czmqpp.

czmq contains a [ZAP handler implementation](https://github.com/zeromq/czmq/blob/master/src/zauth.c), which is described at http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zauth.